# Unable for supervisorctl to run the start script

Tags: linux, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, supervisord

I have this two files, one for the supervisor config and one for the start script.

- start.sh

```
    #!/bin/bash
    cd api
    uvicorn app.main:app --host=0.0.0.0 --workers=2
```

- supervisor conf

```
   [program:uvicorn]
   socket=tcp://localhost:8000
   command=/home/ubuntu/start.sh
   numprocs=2
   process_name=fastapi-uvicorn-%(process_num)d
   stdout_logfile=/var/log/supervisor/fastapi_access.log
   stderr_logfile=/var/log/supervisor/fastapi_error.log
   autostart=true
   autorestart=true
   stopasgroup=true
   stopsignal=QUIT
```

- logfile:

```
   /home/ubuntu/start.sh: line 2: cd: api: No such file or directory
   /home/ubuntu/start.sh: line 4: uvicorn: command not found
   /home/ubuntu/start.sh: line 2: cd: api: No such file or directory
   /home/ubuntu/start.sh: line 4: uvicorn: command not found
   /home/ubuntu/start.sh: line 2: cd: api: No such file or directory
   /home/ubuntu/start.sh: line 4: uvicorn: command not found
```

I think these two files are ok but for some reason it isnt working, i have all my requirements installed on my global, also have tried activating a virtual env but isnt working either.
Also in my /home/ubuntu/ there are only two things, the "api" directory and the start.sh script.
**UPDATE**: i added directory=/home/ubuntu/ into the conf and it seems to fix the direcotry problem but the uvicorn one persists.
**UPDATE 2** i added the path to the uvicorn and now it started, the only problem its that its not showing up the api into the ip, but when i run it manually it works

Thanks for reading!

Comment: Do you know what directory is the "working directory" when the script launches?  It's not the same as the directory containing the script.  Perhaps you should consider using an absolute path instead.

Comment: @TimRoberts I just posted the answer, had to hardcode all the paths for it to work, im a newbie in things like infra and ec2

Comment: For what it's worth, the same thing happens with local systems when you do things like cron scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Update and final answer on this topic, maybe it helps some newbies in infra like me.
I had to add the "directory" statement to the conf for it to really find the api directory and also i had to add the full path to the uvicorn to be able to run the commands, also had to export my env vars into the start script because i wasnt able to add them into the supervisord conf.
Here is how my files worked.

- conf

  ```
      [program:uvicorn]
      socket=tcp://localhost:8000
      directory=/home/ubuntu/
      command=/bin/bash /home/ubuntu/start.sh
      numprocs=2
      process_name=fastapi-uvicorn-%(process_num)d
      stdout_logfile=/var/log/supervisor/fastapi_access.log
      stderr_logfile=/var/log/supervisor/fastapi_error.log
      autostart=true
      autorestart=true
      stopasgroup=true
      stopsignal=QUIT
  ```
- start script

  ```
      #!/bin/bash
      cd api
      export SECRET_KEY="data"
      export ENVIRONMENT="data"
      export ACCESS_TOKEN_EXPIRE_MINUTES=data
      export REFRESH_TOKEN_EXPIRE_MINUTES=data
      export DEFAULT_DATABASE_HOSTNAME="data"
      export DEFAULT_DATABASE_USER="default"
      export DEFAULT_DATABASE_PASSWORD="data"
      export DEFAULT_DATABASE_PORT=data
      export DEFAULT_DATABASE_DB="data"

      /home/ubuntu/.pyenv/versions/3.11.4/bin/uvicorn app.main:app -- 
      host=0.0.0.0 --workers=2
  ```